# Is there a Stack Overflow Discord server?

Tags: discussion

I don't use the chat feature here very often (I do on other SE sites such as the Arqade), but I'm frequently on Discord. I'm curious if Stack Overflow has an *unofficial* Discord server that frequent SO users communicate on outside of chat. I tried searching the communities list on Discord and yielded no results. However, Discord servers can be private when created and as such the server *could* be by invitation only.

---

Is there a Stack Overflow Discord server?

Comment: @KevinB Overall, yes. Sorry, just thought the opening statement was a bit misleading given my expectations was all.

Comment: @Zoe That seems like a good answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I concur with @TylerH on that.

Comment: I dunno, folks, this is a legitimate question we have here for once - not sure what's there to disagree with. It's not like it's about making the company host a voice chat server :) Pretty sure it is also a question that does not have a dupe target to hammer against. It also does not exhibit the "I need a human touch you lack, soulless machines" attitude, so what gives?

Comment: Unrelated, I've never understood the choice of name. If there is anything the world needs less of it's discord.

Comment: Stack Overflow is used by half the programming world, any programming discord is going to see a good number of Stack Overflow regulars. Take your pick. You could say "but a discord named Stack Overflow would attract people from Stack Overflow" - I disagree. They go to places that are useful, like discord channels dedicated to programming. A discord about Stack Overflow is likely going to be like the subreddit - a giant mess of everything and nothing at the same time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a (community run, non-SE affiliated) [server for meta](https://discord.gg/YwfrSXd), but there isn't one for the entirety of (main) SO, at least none that are significant enough to bring to the attention of the meta lot. Discussions often revolve around meta, which tends to attract a decent chunk of the "regulars".

Some (sub-)communities still have Discords, but they're not easily accessible (read: there's not a central listing directory, and they're sometimes not listed at all. Have fun finding them, if they exist). There are not that many, AFAIK, and they're almost always associated [with chatrooms](//chat.stackoverflow.com). In fact, the meta Discord started as a breakout from the Meta room back in 2019, for reasons that are now irrelevant.

Comment: Also, re: *"I tried searching the communities list on Discord and yielded no results."* in the question. You wouldn't find it there, we had the discussion and decided best not to enable Community on the server due to the additional requirements, restrictions, verification, etc. that it requires while not actually giving anything useful (to us) in return.